# SSH Connection Refused In CentOS?

Tags: centos, ssh, terminal, sshd, openssh

For a week, SSH was working perfectly. Today I restarted my server and I got this error in my Mac terminal:

```
ssh: connect to host 162.243.7.7 port 22: Connection refused
```

This is very odd...

I am not sure if I installed anything yesterday that would interfere with port 22. I installed `vsftpd`, but that uses port 21.

I ran the command `ssh -vvv dougieb36@162.243.7.7` in the terminal to get more information. Here are my results:

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.7
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 162.243.7.7 [162.243.7.7] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 162.243.7.7 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 162.243.7.7 port 22: Connection refused
```

Next, I went to my actual server and typed `service sshd status` and got this(sorry that I couldn't get this in text. DigitalOcean doesn't let me copy from their terminal):

[image: The status of SSHD]

Here is part of what `journalctl -u sshd.service` outputs:

[image: journalctl -u sshd.service]

**Anyone know what is happening?** My config file didn't change at all. This is a bit frustrating.

Comment: what is in server log (`/var/log/secure`)?

Comment: Where should I look in the file? It is huge. I'm not quite sure if that file records connection attempts that result in "Connection refused"; If so, I didn't see anything when I tailed it.

Comment: I would open it in a viewer, go to the end of the file, and search backwards for "ssh".  Like this:  `less -i /var/log/secure`,  hit `G` to go to the end of the file, type `?ssh`<enter>,  hit `n` to repeat search, until you see something interesting or not.

Comment: Weird. I can't find anything passed November 8th using the `less` command. Didn't really see anything weird while searching for 'ssh' either.

Comment: Anything interesting in `journalctl -u sshd.service`?

Comment: Just added a screenshot to my question. It says that my config doesn't exist, but when I `nano` the file, it comes up as expected. This is off topic, but I'm thinking of starting the server from scratch and using zPanel. Do you think that's a good idea? I feel a GUI will make this a lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

Server log says

```
sshd: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: No such file or directory
```

This means the the server is unable to open the file for some reason. Check if the file exists and if it has appropriate permissions (including SELinux labels)

```
ls -lZ /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

should give you enough information to figure this out (`restorecon /etc/ssh/sshd_config` should fix SELinux label, if it is wrong).

Answer (score 0):

It's because of ip conflict, I have same kind of issue, you should not use the same ip for other vm's. Even if you delete  it, ip won't be released. try with another ip in the same network it should work.